# Define a rule happened_before(X,Y) which defines the relation that event X happened before event Y using system predicates

Tags: prolog, unification

I can't figure out how to write the answer to the question. Any help is appreciated. I understand the logic behind it but can't find the correct syntax.

> Define a rule happened_before(X,Y) which defines the relation that
>   event X happened before event Y, and use it to obtain all such pairs
>   of events. You will need to use the system predicate <, less than. For
>   example ?- (5 < 7). succeeds. Suitably instantiated variables can be
>   used either side of < instead of numbers. Start the rule with
>   happened_before(X,Y) :-.

my attempt is as follows:

```
event(battle_of_hastings, 1066).
event(plague_of_london, 1665).
event(fire_of_london, 1666).
event(man_on_the_moon, 1969). 

happened_before(X,Y) :-
    (Event1, Y1),
    (Event2, Y2).
    Y1 < Y2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.

What you desired is

```
happened_before(Event1,Event2) :-
    event(Event1, Y1),
    event(Event2, Y2),
    Y1 < Y2.
```

Prolog is about [syntactic unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Examples_of_syntactic_unification_of_first-order_terms) which can often be thought simply as matching [terms](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary).

In this case a line like `event(Event1, Y1)` which is in itself is known as a [goal](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary) needs to match against something to work ([succeed](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary)). You have [facts](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary) which you are trying to match.

So

`event` (the [functor](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary)) in `event(Event1, Y1)` needs to match with `event` in a fact like `event(battle_of_hastings, 1066).`.

Then the number of [arguments](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary) needs to match which in this case they both have 2 arguments.

Now since the goal has two [variables](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary) (begin with upper case letter) they will match ([unify](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary)) with the corresponding parts of the facts. Thus

`Event1` unifies with `battle_of_hastings` and
`Y1` unifies with `1066`.

---

The reason you need to match on the functor is because if you have a fact like

```
time(battle_of_hastings, 1066).
```

and a query like you had `(Event1,Y1)` with the way you intended it to work  without a functor, the match would succeed on unifying when you did not want it too.

---

Another way to think about unification of terms that reinforces the need to check the functor when unifying is this variation of Prolog terms from days gone by

`event(battle_of_hastings, 1066)`

in the past would be

`(event, battle_of_hastings, 1066)`

where the name was the first argument and it was thus apparent that it also needed to be unified.

---

Here is all the code with test cases.

```
event(battle_of_hastings, 1066).
event(plague_of_london, 1665).
event(fire_of_london, 1666).
event(man_on_the_moon, 1969).

happened_before(Event1,Event2) :-
    event(Event1, Y1),
    event(Event2, Y2),
    Y1 < Y2.


:- begin_tests(happened_before).

happened_before_test_case_generator(success,plague_of_london,fire_of_london).
happened_before_test_case_generator(success,plague_of_london,man_on_the_moon).
happened_before_test_case_generator(fail,plague_of_london,plague_of_london).
happened_before_test_case_generator(fail,fire_of_london,plague_of_london).
happened_before_test_case_generator(fail,man_on_the_moon,plague_of_london).

test(01,[forall(happened_before_test_case_generator(success,Event1,Event2))]) :-
    happened_before(Event1,Event2).

test(02,[fail,forall(happened_before_test_case_generator(fail,Event1,Event2))]) :-
    happened_before(Event1,Event2).

:- end_tests(happened_before).
```

Example run of tests.

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: happened_before ..... done
% All 5 tests passed
true.
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, it's very clear and easy to understand. Very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @LukeHeald If you ask a good question that is simple and has code, you get such a response. It was a pleasure to answer this question. No discussion needed to figure out your problem.

Comment: @LukeHeald As you are probably taking this in a class, ask the instructor why he didn't give you test cases. In other words I am trying get the instructors to be better instructors by not only giving out the format of the goal e,g. `happened_before(X,Y) :-` but the expected results. Would make it easier for the students and those helping the students.

Comment: @GuyCoder: `true.`